# Installing Guake in Anaconda Environment

Tags: ubuntu, python, guake

I'm using anaconda to manage virtual environments on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine.

For some reason, I'm not able to use the Guake terminal anymore:

```
anaconda3/bin/python2: No module named guake
```

(Default environment). It used to work until now. I suspect that there is an issue with some paths.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/guake
```

I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922328/ubuntu-16-04-default-python-environment-in-my-user-profile-is-anaconda-python2). However, I don't know how I can install the packages within the anaconda environment.

I tried reinstalling guake from the repository as well as compiling the source. The latter gives the following error:

```
configure: error: cannot import Python module "vte".
Please check if you have python-vte installed. The error was:
No module named vte
```

I suspect it is installed in the wrong folder. The script should install all dependencies (according to the describtion on the guake github page) but I guess it does so in the wrong location.

Does anyone know how I can cleanly install packages within the anaconda environment without using conda install ..  Is this a good idea at all? Or can I update some path variables?  I'm a bit lost.  (Furthermore, if someone knows alternative drop-down terminals I would be glad to know)

Answer (score 1):

My Ubuntu is 16.10.(I haven't used Ubuntu for a month.)
I had same problem.

Now by just running guake-indicator, it goes well.

(I can't use "guake" command on terminal nor "guake-indicator" yet,
but it is not a problem if you just want to use guake. )

Of course,I add guake-indicator to startup applications.

You should try it.